# How to merge objects that's inside an array using native javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, javascript-objects

I have an api that gives me the right data, but it's mostly the same data in each object. I want to restructure the objects in the array into one object.

This is the data that my api products currently.

```
 var data = [
     {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Abrasives 
    Accessories"},
     {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Non-woven 
     Abrasives"},
     {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Bonded 
     Abrasives"},
     {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Wire Brushes"},
    {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Coated 
    Abrasives"},

{maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Specialty    
    Abrasives"},
    {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Super 
    Abrasives"}
    ];

var transformed= data.map(function(obj){
    var result= {
        key: obj.maincategory,
        values: []
    }
console.log(result)
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== "maincategory") {
          result.values.push([key, obj[key]]);
      }
    }
    return result;
});

console.log(transformed);
```

This is how I would like the data to be structured.

```
var data = [
  { 
     maincategory: "AP",
     maincatname: "Abrasives",
     subcatname: ['Abrasives Accessories','Non-woven Abrasives','Bonded Abrasives','Wire Brushes', etc]
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.values()`. Create an object lookup with `maincategory` and add `maincategory`, `maincatname` and `subcatname` corresponding to it and then take out values using `Object.values()` from this object.

```js
var data = [ {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Abrasives Accessories"}, {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Non-woven Abrasives"}, {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Bonded Abrasives"},{maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Wire Brushes"}, {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Coated Abrasives"}, {maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Specialty Abrasives"}, {maincategory:"AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Super Abrasives"} ]
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, {maincategory, maincatname, subcatname}) => {
      r[maincategory] = r[maincategory] || {maincategory, maincatname, subcatname : []};
      r[maincategory].subcatname.push(subcatname);
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it's always the same data then you can have your result by using this function:

```
function transform(data){
  obj = {};
  obj['maincategory'] = data[0]['maincategory'];
  obj['maincatname'] = data[0]['maincatname'];
  obj['subcatnames'] = data.map(function(obj){ 
                       return obj.subcatname});
  return [obj]
}
```

To be honest the best solution is to fix the `api` to return a more structured results.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, while all the answers provided the same output. This answer was the most simple to understand. Thank everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**`Array.reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get that output:

```js
var data = [{ maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Abrasives Accessories" }, { maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Non-woven Abrasives" }, { maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Bonded Abrasives" }, { maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Wire Brushes" }, { maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Coated Abrasives" }, { maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Specialty Abrasives" }, { maincategory: "AP", maincatname: "Abrasives", subcatname: "Super Abrasives" }]

const r = data.reduce((r,c) => (r.subcatname = [...Array.isArray(r.subcatname) 
  ? r.subcatname 
  : [r.subcatname], c.subcatname], r)) 

console.log(r)
```

The idea is since you only need the `subcatname` to be combined you can just use the `Array.reduce` and its basic form where it essentially acts as a `merge`.